# Execute file from Android device programatically

Tags: java, android, file

I have finished my Chess UI application and now want to load a chess engine to test if my UI truly is UCI-compatible. The chess engine is inside the Download folder of  the Android device ('/storage/emulated/0/Download'). This is the code that is run:

```
try {
        File f  = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        String stockfishPath = path + "/Stockfish-9-armv64v8";
        engineProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(stockfishPath);
        processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                engineProcess.getInputStream()));

        String sCurrentLine;

        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((sCurrentLine = processReader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.add(sCurrentLine);
        }

        processWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                engineProcess.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this it fails on the exec() method because it claims it cannot find the file, even though the file exists on the Android device. I tried running the "ls" command on the exec() method, but the folder inside "emulated" is empty. The obvious reason for this is probably because I do not have permission to view/access these files, but I need to know how I can do that (despite adding the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest file).

Is it maybe possible to embed the engine somewhere in the project (in resources?) and somehow adb-shell into that?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that, simply because the SD card is being mounted with `-noexec` flag.

using the internal storage with `chmod +x` would be the only option available.

Comment: It is internal storage. There is no SD-card. Could you give and example with the chmod +x with the exec method specified?

Comment: @DanZoe this is not the internal storage; just see how often you've used the word external above. use `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()` and `.exec("chmod +x " + stockfishPath)`. while it possibly might not run without root, because the SE Linux labels could prevent it from doing so - and unless being root, there is no `semanage` command available to label the file.

Comment: I see. Is there another way of executing the stockfish executable. I have searched and searched, and the only thing I need, is to actually execute it, no matter the location. Do you have any tips?

Comment: @DanZoe have you tried the suggested method yet? "I see" does not exactly sound alike.